# Batch setting Parentheses right

Tags: batch-file, parentheses

i don't get it :/
Batch is so weird.
Could you help me get this work?
All I get is that something is in wrong position.
I think the parentheses at the ifs are wrong.
I tried multiple combinations but none worked :/

```
:init
set ergebniss=
set laufzeit=
set zinssatz=
set skapital=
set i=
set help=

:input1
if NOT (%1)==()(
    set /a skapital=%1
    set /a zahl=%skapital% + 0
    goto input2
    if %zahl% neq %skapital% (
        cls
        echo Ungueltiges Startkapital!
        goto startkapital
    )
)

:startkapital
cls
echo Geben Sie ein Startkapital ein:
set /p skapital= 
set /a zahl=%skapital% + 0
if %zahl% neq %skapital% (
    cls
    echo Ungueltiges Startkapital!
    goto startkapital
)

:input2
if NOT (%2)==() (
    set /a zinssatz=%2
    set /a zahl=%zinssatz% + 0
    goto input3
    if %zahl% neq %zinssatz% (
        cls
        echo Ungueltiger Zinssatz!
        goto zinssatz
    )
)

:zinssatz
pause
cls
echo Geben sie den Zinssatz ein:
set /p zinssatz= 
set /a zahl=%zinssatz% + 0
if %zahl% neq %zinssatz% (
    cls
    echo Ungueltiger Zinssatz!
    goto zinssatz
)

:input3
if NOT (%3)==() (
    set /a laufzeit=%3
    set /a zahl=%laufzeit% + 0
    goto input3
    if %zahl% neq %laufzeit% (
        cls
        echo Ungueltige Laufzeit
        goto laufzeit
    )
)

:laufzeit
pause
cls
echo Geben sie eine Laufzeit ein:
set /p laufzeit= 
set /a zahl=%laufzeit% + 0
if %zahl% neq %laufzeit% (
    cls
    echo Ungueltige Laufzeit
    goto laufzeit
)

:berechne
set ergebniss=%skapital%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%i in (1,1,%laufzeit%) do  set  /a ergebniss=!ergebniss!+!ergebniss!*%zinssatz%/100

:ausgabe
cls
echo Das Kapital nach %laufzeit% Jahren ist %ergebniss%

:wiederhole
echo Wiederholen? [j/n]: 
set /p wh=
if "%wh%"=="j" (
    cls
    goto init )
```

---

Revised code:

```
:init
set ergebniss=
set laufzeit=
set zinssatz=
set skapital=
set i=
set help=
set zahl=

:input1
if NOT (%1)==() (
    set /a skapital=%1
    set /a zahl=%skapital% + 0
    if %zahl% neq %skapital% (
        cls
        echo Ungueltiges Startkapital!
        goto startkapital
    )
    goto input2
)

:startkapital
cls
echo Geben Sie ein Startkapital ein:
set /p skapital= 
set /a zahl=%skapital% + 0
if %zahl% neq %skapital% (
    cls
    echo Ungueltiges Startkapital!
    goto startkapital
)

:input2
if NOT (%2)==() (
    set /a zinssatz=%2
    set /a zahl=%zinssatz% + 0
    if %zahl% neq %zinssatz% (
        cls
        echo Ungueltiger Zinssatz!
        goto zinssatz
    )
    goto input3
)

:zinssatz
pause
cls
echo Geben sie den Zinssatz ein:
set /p zinssatz= 
set /a zahl=%zinssatz% + 0
if %zahl% neq %zinssatz% (
    cls
    echo Ungueltiger Zinssatz!
    goto zinssatz
)

:input3
if NOT (%3)==() (
    set /a laufzeit=%3
    set /a zahl=%laufzeit% + 0
    if %zahl% neq %laufzeit% (
        cls
        echo Ungueltige Laufzeit
        goto laufzeit
    )
    goto input3
)

:laufzeit
pause
cls
echo Geben sie eine Laufzeit ein:
set /p laufzeit= 
set /a zahl=%laufzeit% + 0
if %zahl% neq %laufzeit% (
    cls
    echo Ungueltige Laufzeit
    goto laufzeit
)

:berechne
set ergebniss=%skapital%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%i in (1,1,%laufzeit%) do  set  /a ergebniss=!ergebniss!+!ergebniss!*%zinssatz%/100

:ausgabe
cls
echo Das Kapital nach %laufzeit% Jahren ist %ergebniss%

:wiederhole
echo Wiederholen? [j/n]: 
set /p wh=
if "%wh%"=="j" (
    cls
    goto init )
```

Solution:

```
:input1
if (%1)==() goto startkapital
set /a skapital=%1
set /a zahl=%skapital% + 0
if %zahl% neq %skapital% (
    cls
    echo Ungueltiges Startkapital!
    goto startkapital
)
goto input2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if NOT (%1)==()(
```

There must be a space before that final parenthesis, else batch has no way of telling whether your instruction is `if NOT "(%1)"=="()("` or `if NOT "(%1)"=="()" (`

(and btw, `if "%1" neq "" (` is equivalent and more robust)

Note

```
:input1
if NOT (%1)==() (
    set /a skapital=%1
    set /a zahl=%skapital% + 0
    goto input2
```

> This following code won't be executed since execution has been transferred to `:input2`

```
    if %zahl% neq %skapital% (
```

> Even if this code *was* executed, `zahl` is not defined at this point. You need to read about `delayed expansion` if you vary a variable within a code `block` (parenthesised sequence of code)

```
        cls
        echo Ungueltiges Startkapital!
        goto startkapital
    )
)
```

This problem is repeated over you following code.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for helping me out a bit.

Comment: If I write the code like that: :input1
if NOT (%1)==() (
 set /a skapital=%1
 set /a zahl=%skapital% + 0
 if %zahl% neq %skapital% (
  cls
  echo Ungueltiges Startkapital!
  goto startkapital
 )
 goto input2
) I get "( was unexpected at this time"

Comment: You would need to `edit` this code into your question as an addition. Batch can show sensitivity tolayout and it's not clear where the linebreaks are.

Comment: I updated my code to what I have now

Comment: Edit note : you should not change your original posting as it makes potentially nonsense of the narrative. Simply add new info.

Comment: oh yeah. thanks for the tipp. i am very new to stackoverflow ^^

Comment: Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`. Hence, `if %zahl% neq %skapital% (` will be evaluated as `if  neq (` since neither `zahk` nor `skapital` are established when the outermost code block begins. You need to read about `delayed expansion` (SO has many hundreds of items - it's probably the most frequent question)

Comment: ahh nvm i am so dumb xD

Comment: Actually `if "%1" neq "" (` is not equivalent (nor more robust) because it will fail if `"&"` is passed. Better to use `if "%~1" neq "" (`